# Creating Triangular Multiplication Table using Do-while Loop

Tags: java, do-while

I want to ask a question or a probable favor on how am I going to make my program coding "do-while loop" in creating a Triangular Multiplication. Is there a probable way on to create such thing without using any other statement?

```
public class Main {
  static void ssbr(int n) {
    int i = 1;
    
    do{
    System.out.printf("%4d", n * i);
    i = i + 1;
    } while(i <= 7);
    System.out.println("");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    do{
    ssbr(i);
            i = i + 1;
        } while (i <= 7);
    }
}
```

Output it gave:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  4  6  8 10 11 12
3  6  9 12 15 18 21
4  8 12 16 20 24 30
5 10 15 20 25 30 35
6 12 18 24 30 36 42
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

Output I wanted:

```
1
2  4
3  6  9
4  8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger: think about the point at which you want it to stop looping, and think about how to change the condition to do that.

Comment: (BTW, why use do/while? This would be far better written with a for loop; there is no obvious point in contriving to use do/while here).

Comment: So there is really no other way, huh. I felt confused when our teacher in programming asked us to do a triangular table output using do-while loop with poor teaching skill she left us, we(i) really don't know what to do.

Comment: @Majima - I suggest you study https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html thoroughly. A `for` loop can be easily converted into `while` or `do-while` loop if you understand the basic concept of these loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following algorithm:

1. You have to do it `7` times and therefore you can use a loop that should run `7` times.
2. Each row starts with the row number, and run for row number * row number times with a step-value equal to the row number.

Given below is the implementation of this algorithm using `for` loop and I leave it to you to implement it using the `do-while` loop (as it seems to be your homework )

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 7;
        for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
            for (int col = row; col <= row * row; col += row) {
                System.out.printf("%-4d", col);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1   
2   4   
3   6   9   
4   8   12  16  
5   10  15  20  25  
6   12  18  24  30  36  
7   14  21  28  35  42  49
```